How to find the digits a, b and c?
I am trying to solve the following mathematical expression:
$\frac{1}{a+b+c}=0,abc$
Where a, b and c represent digits. My goal is to find the values ​​of the digits a, b and c.
I have tried to multiply with 1000 and got 1000=100x^2+100xy+100xz+10xy+10y^2+10yz+xz+yz+c^2  but i  have not been able to come up with a solution. Can anyone provide me with guidance or a solution to this expression?
Thanks in advance!

Given that these are digits, brute force seems like a sensible approach.  In any event, it's a natural place to start.

yeah but this question is from theory of numbers, so i dont think the brute force is a good answer. I tried to multiply everything with 1000  and now i am stuck

*I have tried several approaches.” Please tell what exactly did you try.

Please edit your post to show some effort.  Note that the three digit number $\overline {abc}$ must be a divisor of $1000$ so brute force is easy.

Hint : You have $\frac{1}{a+b+c}=\frac{a}{10}+\frac{b}{100}+\frac{c}{1000}$ , clearing the denominators gives $1000=(a+b+c)(100a+10b+c)$ , so you only have to check the divisors of $1000$ with $3$ digits , namely $[100, 125, 200, 250, 500]$

The q was closed, there can be no more answers, so why was I unaccepted?

Let's see how many trials are really needed.

$\overline{abc}=100a+10b+c$ must be a divisor of $1000$.

If the divisor has fewer than three digits, then $a=0$, and then $a+b+c<20$ and $\overline{abc}>50$. This is contradictory as there are no two-digit divisors of $1000$ greater than $50$. So $\overline{abc}$ is a three-digit number and must be $\in\{100,125,200,250,500\}$.

Modulo $9$ we have $(a+b+c)^2\equiv1$, and with $9$ having only one distinct prime factor this implies $a+b+c\equiv\pm1$.

Finally, we must have $a+b+c>1$ to get less than $1$ on the right side.


If you've been paying attention, you see that $\overline{abc}=125$ is the only surviving candidate. We can solve the problem with one trial!
